# About a specific PHP&MySQLCode Performance Logic Helping

Tags: mysql, performance

I use Laravel 6 for one of my app. I am stuck in a **performance problem** for post page in my app.

The most popular page is post page in my app. Typically the post page has:

- PostPage content,
- Comments of post content and **subComments** (as tree) for all comment,
- and comment liking, rating (Is the member liked this comment) again for all comment

E.g: if the page has +10 comments, the app will be, slowly and mysqld high.

**An example for SQL Query in my code block:**

```
 SELECT `comments`.`id`, `comments`.`comment`, `comments`.`parent_id`, `comments`.`date`,
 `comments`.`ratingN`, `comments`.`ratingP`, `rating`.`rate`, `users`.`photo`, 
 `users`.`photo2`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`gold_end`,  
 (CASE WHEN rating.id_user = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as liked   

 FROM `comments` 
 inner join `users` on `comments`.`id_user` = `users`.`id` 
 left join `rating` on `rating`.`id_comment` = `comments`.`id` 
 where `parent_id` = 284162 and `status` = 1 
 group by `comments`.`date` order by `date` asc
```

I use (query) cache but again the first opening and after any update the post page works slowly because of comments side. Using joins.

- I call the **main comments** and than, look that **mainComments have any subComments**,
- The comments are **liked by this member**?

PHP 7.2, MySQL 5.7

What are your suggestions?

Comment: What table is `status` in?  Is `date` unique?  If not, the `GROUP BY` does not make sense.  Once those are straightened out, I may have some composite index suggestions.

Comment: Status means active / passive. Yes, date is uniqe (timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

These composite indexes might help:

```
comments:  INDEX(parent_id, status, date)
rating:  INDEX(id_comment, id_user, rate)
users:  I assume you have `PRIMARY KEY(Id)`?
```

Comment: Yes, 
comments table has, parent_id, status, date
rating: id_comment,id_user, rate and again yes,
users has Id (as primary).

Comment: @JackUK - I should have said that these were suggested indexes.

Comment: Ohh no! 

Just Id is primary, but id_comment, id_user, id_post don't have index (rating table).

Comments table is also same: It has just an index for Id as primary. (id_user, id_post,parent_id are normal, no index)

What should I do, Add new Index as Key, or Add to index as Primary?

Comment: @JackUK - Leave the PK alone, `ALTER TABLE ... ADD INDEX(...)`.  And read about indexing; it is a key feature of RDBMs.